# Channel configuration in connman

Tags: networking, hostapd, connman

I am trying to establish a Wi-Fi access point. I tried using hostapd and connman. In hostapd I am able to configure channel number in hostapd.conf, whereas in the case of connman there is no parameter available to configure channel in main.conf.

I am badly struck to know the parameter to configure channel in connman.
If so then is it the difference in hostapd and connman

Answer (score 0):

Connman does not have channel configuration facility like hostapd.

hostapd provides ACS- Automatic Channel Selection along with static channel selection.

Check [hostapd](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf) configuration page for more details on it.